# Mysql Random item in group and count item in group

Tags: mysql, optimization

[image]Hello all the below query is very slow I cant seem to optimise it.

I have tried two ways. Both very slow.

I need to get a random item from each image_tag and also the amount of images that belongs to a tag. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Querying taking two mins to execute either way. Slow in relation to the image count and the join. Image count by itself very fast. When on the join very slow.

```
SELECT T.id, T.title, T.guid_id, T.hits, al.title, tt.title, tt.raw, it.tag_title_id
,((ACOS(SIN(53.38946 * PI() / 180) * SIN(geo.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(53.38946 * PI() / 180) 
* COS(geo.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((-2.599586 - geo.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
AS distance, uf.real_name, uf.user_name, itx.image_count
FROM 
     (SELECT imx.id, imx.guid_id,  imx.user_id, imx.approved, imx.hits, imx.title, imx.visible, imx.geolocation_id, imx.advertise_to
      FROM image imx
      ORDER BY floor(RAND()*(SELECT count(1) FROM image)))
      AS T
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON T.id = it.image_id 
INNER JOIN tag_title tt ON it.tag_title_id =tt.id
INNER JOIN album_image ai ON T.id = ai.image_id
INNER JOIN album al ON ai.album_id = al.id
INNER JOIN user us ON T.user_id = us.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf ON us.flickr_id = uf.id
LEFT JOIN user_site uss ON us.user_site_id= uss.id
LEFT JOIN geolocation geo ON T.geolocation_id = geo.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, count(*) as image_count FROM image_tag GROUP BY image_id) itx ON itx.image_id = T.id 
WHERE T.visible = in_image_visible
AND T.approved = in_image_approved
AND (T.advertise_to <= in_date_time_now OR T.advertise_to IS NULL)
GROUP BY tt.id;
```

This is fast

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT image_id, count(*) as image_count 
    FROM image_tag it
    GROUP BY image_id) T
INNER JOIN image im ON T.image_id = im.id
```

When i add the random logic on the join it is very slow

Comment: Whhat happens to performance when you remove that mass of trigonometry?

Comment: very slow still trigonometry no performance impact on it

Comment: Can you run this through an `EXPLAIN` and provide the results?

Comment: I have attached explain

Comment: I can't read that image; can you run it from the command line and provide the actual text>

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have two `filesorts` in your query on over 20,000 rows.

This means that you're sorting without the benefit of an index, which, with this many rows, is going to be slow.

I suggest that you ditch the random ordering... do that with whatever language you're processing your PHP results with. That'll remove one of the filesorts. If that gets things to a reasonable level, then great.

Comment: i added random ordering to select a different item from each group- is there any other way to do this

Comment: basically trying to select a different item each group and the number of images per group

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method for getting a random image:

```
  SELECT imx.id, imx.guid_id,  imx.user_id, imx.approved, imx.hits, imx.title, imx.visible, imx.geolocation_id, imx.advertise_to
  FROM image imx
  ORDER BY rand()
```

The additional subquery cannot be helping matters.